# GoogleTV Invoke another application from a status bar notification

Tags: android, google-tv

I am new to Android GoogleTV development.
My requirement is that one of my service running in the background will provide user with a status bar notification.From a status bar notification, when the user clicks on it , another built in application / Built in chrome Browser (with a predefined URL) should start up.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please provide the previous research you have done on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - when the user clicks on your notification, it can launch what ever intent you want it to.  This is done using `Notification.Builder.SetContentIntent()` It can be an intent for any application.